# PostgreSQL 9.6 performance issue due to sequential scan insted of index

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing

I am encountering a performance issue with PostgreSQL 9.6.
I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cdrsinfo (
  recordid bigint NOT NULL,
  billid integer,
  CONSTRAINT cdrsinfo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (recordid) );
```

And a index created on it like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cdrsinfo_pkey ON cdrsinfo USING btree (recordid)

CREATE INDEX indx_cdrsinfo_billid ON cdrsinfo USING btree (billid)
```

The table has around 3M records, I've done the analyze on it and when running the following queries with EXPLAIN I get some strange results :

```
SELECT max(recordid) FROM example WHERE billid = 535;

Result  (cost=26631.27..26631.28 rows=1 width=8)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..26631.27 rows=1 width=8)
          ->  Index Scan Backward using cdrsinfo_pkey on cdrsinfo  (cost=0.57..2291944283.82 rows=86064 width=8)
                Index Cond: (recordid IS NOT NULL)
                Filter: (billid = 535)


SELECT max(recordid) FROM example WHERE billid < 535;

Aggregate  (cost=725.85..725.86 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Index Scan using indx_cdrsinfo_billid on cdrsinfo  (cost=0.57..725.37 rows=192 width=8)
        Index Cond: (billid < 535)
```

If I do a count of all the rows that have the `billid = 535` I get 44 . My question is why doesn't the query planner use the `indx_cdrsinfo_billid` in the first example ?
I get huge performance issues because of this, this first SQL takes ~2 hours to complete and the second one ~170 ms .

I forgot to mention a 3rd index that I have on the table :

```
CREATE INDEX indx_cdrsinfo_billid_recordid ON cdrsinfo USING btree (recordid,billid)
```

As I mentioned the table was analyzed before running the query . Now when I executed the explain with analyze verbose and buffers I get a very good time on the same query where billid = 535 :

```
Result  (cost=0.85..0.86 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.034..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: $0
  Buffers: shared hit=5
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..0.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
          Output: cdrsinfo.recordid
          Buffers: shared hit=5
          ->  Index Only Scan Backward using indx_cdrsinfo_billid_recordid on public.cdrsinfo  (cost=0.57..24041.88 rows=89007 width=8) (actual  time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
                Output: cdrsinfo.recordid
                Index Cond: ((cdrsinfo.billid = 535) AND (cdrsinfo.recordid IS NOT NULL))
                Heap Fetches: 0
                Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning time: 0.177 ms
Execution time: 0.056 ms
```

The index was there in the past too, I don't understand why the Query Planner decided to use it now and not this morning .

Another strange thing when I got that very awful execution time I tried to re-write that query in several modes to see the explain plan and when I do it like this :

```
SELECT max(recordid) FROM cdrsinfo WHERE recordid IN (SELECT recordid FROM cdrsinfo WHERE billid = 535 OFFSET 0)
```

Because of the OFFSET 0 the Query Planner used the indx_cdrsinfo_billid, the one that I would expect to be used .

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` for the slow query

Comment: Try performing 'analyze' on your table and update the stats for it.

Comment: In addition to that, what do you get for `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT 1 FROM example WHERE billid = 535`?

Comment: You can maybe also test using `ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1` instead of `max()` and see does it make difference in your case?

Comment: Why didn't you use the optimal, compound index (i.e. `(billid, recordid)`) instead?

Comment: Also, are you sure about that `create table` statement? `CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(recordid)` is not valid. And the `Index Cond: (recordid IS NOT NULL)` suggests that you have no `NOT NULL` constraint on `recordid` (thus it's not a primary key either).

Comment: Sorry for the statement I manually wrote it in a hurry, the create table from pgAdmin is the following : CREATE TABLE public.cdrsinfo
(
  recordid bigint NOT NULL,
  billid integer,
  CONSTRAINT cdrsinfo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (recordid)
)

Comment: Your compound index is still is in wrong order. Are your other queries use that specific order? If not, try to switch them. Or even `(billid, recordid DESC)` if you only interested in `max()`.